# React.JS not rendering new views in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, reactjs

I have a React project I am working on and everything has been going great. However when I tried to test my site in IE11 I get this rendering issue. It will have no problem rendering the intial home page, but when I try to click a link to see a different view I get this error:

```
Unable to get property 'getNativeNode' of undefined or null reference
```

and the error happens here

```
getNativeNode: function (internalInstance) {
     return internalInstance.getNativeNode();
}
```

I am trying to figure out why I am getting this issue and also how to resolve it. I see quite a bit of IE11 issues with react online but havent found a solution for my issue so far. I am current using no polyfills or anything for IE yet, so hopefully its just a matter a polyfill.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue in my application. Internet Explorer has an ongoing issue with the HTTP Cache.

I resolved it by setting `cache: true` in my webpack entry array.